# Dictionary Manipulations in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to store the following values into a dictionary:

key (string) - values (list of strings)

```
aaa - myfirstvalue1
aaa - myfirstvalue2

bbb - myfirstvalue3

ccc - myfirstvalue4
ccc - myfirstvalue5
```

Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string> myvalues = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I tried to store these values but I got the duplicate key error.

Comment: I want to store first two values store in the aaa key and third values store in bbb key in the dictionary.

Comment: you cannot duplicate keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries have the feature that a key can be added only once. You have the right type, but the way you add the data matters.

You can initialize the dictionary with the data provided like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myvalues = Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        { "aaa", new List<string> { "myfirstvalue1", "myfirstvalue2" } },
        { "bbb", new List<string> { "myfirstvalue3" } },
        { "ccc", new List<string> { "myfirstvalue4", "myfirstvalue5" } },
    };
```

With this, each key has one list of strings assigned to it. You can add more values like this:

```
 var key = "aaa"; // for example
 if (myvalues.ContainsKey(key)
 {
     myvalues[key].Add("new value");
 }
 else
 {
     myvalues.Add(key, new List<string> { "new value" });
 }
```

You can retrieve values like this:

```
 List<string> aaaVals = myvalues["aaa"];
```

and then convert that `List<string>` to an `Array` with [`List.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx).

Comment: after stored values to the myvalues list. how to retrieve the values based on the key and store to string[] array?

Comment: ahh man.. I was just going to write a simiiar approaach for conicating the strings if the key exsists. but the <string,List<string>> is so much cleaner.

Comment: Actually i would like to store the list of values to one key(if the key is same). so hwo to check the condition if the key is appear or not. if the key appear the values should add to that key or else the values should add with new key got it. so how to check the condition help of contains key

Comment: @Lemon It may be more beneficial to find a [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) on how to use the Dictionary, instead of continually expanding your original question.

Comment: @Lemon do not trasform this in a [chamaleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). This answers your original question. If you have a new one ask a new question.

Comment: @Andrew Perfect. if i created one  string[] GRP_List; can i add the list of values to this string list. by check the key values. if(myvalues.contanisey(aaa) {  GRP_List {myvalues.values}}

Comment: If you have a new question, use the Ask Question button to ask it. I've already more than answered your original question as it stands.

Comment: i have create as per your request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431527/how-to-add-teh-dictionary-value-to-string-array

Comment: @Andrew please answer the above link please